# `else if` is never executed; only the preceding `if` is executed

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a function which runs through some `<div>`s, and inside each `<div>` it counts the amount of children. Then, based on the amount of children (`var length`), it does something.

```js
$('.member-type').each(function() {
  var length = $(this).children('.views-row').length;
  
  if (length >= 2) {
    console.log('equal to or more than two');
  }
  else if (length > 5) {
    console.log('more than five');
  }
  else {
    console.log('single item');
  }
});
```

The first `if` statement works and the `else` statement works. But for some reason, the `else if` statement doesn’t work, even when `length` is higher than `5` (I checked in the console log).

Does anyone know what I’m doing wrong?

Comment: your first condition is always true for the second condition, so it will always go in the if part and not else if part.

Comment: I don't think this question should be down-voted. He's come up with an idea, he's made a reasonable attempt at achieving his goal and he's come here with a problem, albeit a simple one, but it's a valid question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When the `length` is greater than `2`, it is *always* greater than `5`, so it will always go in the first `if` statement block. Change the condition in the first `if`, so that the `else` part can be executed:

```js
if (length >= 2 && length <= 5) {
  console.log('more than two and less than five');
}
else if (length > 5) {
  console.log('more than five');
}
else {
  console.log('single item');
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes. The first if ( length>= 2) includes also the second else if (length > 5)

In another words, if the first condition is met, so is the second, so the flow will never reach the second block.

You can change the code for the following (which, I believe, it's easier to understand):

```
if (length >5){
   console.log('more than five');
}
else if (length > 2){
    console.log('more than two');
}
else{
   console.log('single item');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want both the ifs to work you just remove the else, because the else prevents the second if to be executed:

```
$('.member-type').each(function() {
   var length = $(this).children('.views-row').length;
   if (length >= 2){
       console.log('equal to or more than two');
   }
   if (length > 5){
       console.log('more than five');
   }
   else{
       console.log('single item');
   }
});
```